# OpenCV - using VideoWriter gives no file

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, video-capture

I have searched for a solution of my problem on many sites (including stack overflow). I am trying to save a video from my webcam in my Raspberry using OpenCV. Theoretically, my code works fine (I can see my webcam in the window, i can see python printing "frame"), but when it goes to saving the file I cannot see anything. I have found that I should change codecs in FourCC, but it changes nothing.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cv2
import numpy as np

def InitCamera():

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    if cap is None:
        print('No camera access')
    else:
        print('Camera init done')
    return cap

def InitWriter():
    fps = 20
    size = (640,480)
    outFile = 'output.mp4'

    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('R','G','B',' ')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('Y','U','Y','2')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('Y','U','Y','U')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('U','Y','V','Y')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('I','4','2','0')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('I','Y','U','V')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('Y','U','1','2')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('Y','8','0','0')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('G','R','E','Y')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('B','Y','8',' ')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('Y','1','6',' ')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D')
    #fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')
    fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M','P','E','G')

    out = cv2.VideoWriter(outFile, fourcc, fps, size, 1)
    if out is None:
        print('No video access')
    else:
        print('Video init done')
    return out

def CapVideo(cap,out):
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret==True:
            out.write(frame)
            print('frame')
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
                break

        else:
            break
    print 'Done'

    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cam = InitCamera()
    out = InitWriter()
    CapVideo(cam,out)
```

Comment: Did you find solution/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a strong reason to write mp4 files? Consider writing to file with an avi extension. I have struggled with this problem a lot as well and in cases where I strongly needed an MP4 file, i ended up using ffmpeg to do the conversion post writing the file as an avi by openCV.

I was developing on C++ and simply made a system call. Something like this:

```
std::string ffmpeg_conversion_cmd = "ffmpeg -y -i data\\intermediate_result.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -preset slow -c:a libfaac -b:a 192k -ac 2 data\\intermediate_result.mp4";
std::system(ffmpeg_conversion_cmd.c_str());
```

Of course, you need to have ffmpeg installed on your Pi to do this.

Comment: No, i don't need mp4. When i tried using *.avi, it didn't create any file also.

Comment: One more thing to check will be if your frames are indeed of the size (640,480). Instead of defining it yourself, you can get the properties from cap itself by using `cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)` and `cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)`.

Comment: I have checked it. Pritnting cap.get height and width gave me size (640, 480).

Comment: Same here. This is really creazy. Shit. Sometimes the output video file appears and with .write(frame) it is properly filled. "Sometimes" mean: it has happen once. Usually (and now, and probably forever) the output file is not created. But everything looks like it is still correctly working. (cycle with .write() takes the same time,..). /Debian Stretch./